# Intellisense and the Google closure library

Tags: javascript, intellisense, google-closure-library

Are there any files or vsdoc files available to get Intellisense working with the Google closure library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've posted this question and answer for anyone else looking for the same thing, when I discovered I couldn't find any intellisense files for the closure library I implemented my own.

You can find the repository of vsdoc files at 
https://bitbucket.org/SharkAttack/closure-library-vsdoc-intellisense

The vsdoc files are a straight port over from the closure library. They're too large to have intellisense reliable work in one single file. If for example you'd like to get the goog.dom part of intellisense working you would simply need to provide two intellisense references at the top of your JavaScrip file.

```
/// <reference path="goog-vsdoc.js" /> 
/// <reference path="goog.dom-vsdoc.js" />
```

Notice that the first reference just provides the 'goog' namespace. You'll need this with every closure library intellisense reference.

Here is my blog post on the same thing explaining it a little more in depth http://planetaryweb.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/googles-closure-library-intellisense.html